# insert content of nvarchar column into number column from a table into another

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to insert content of  column1 (nvarchar2(2000 char) datatype) of table A into column2
 (number (18,3) datatype)of table B
but i'm given the error

> Erreur SQL : ORA-01722: Nombre non valide

Comment: Seems like you have non-numeric values in your varchar2 column. What should happen for such rows?

Comment: no it only contains numeric values

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression to convert non-convertible values to `NULL`:

```
(case when regexp_like(a.column1, '^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$')
      then to_number(a.column1)
 end)
```

Similarly you can use a `where` clause to filter out the bad values.

Comment: i have already used to_number() to convert values but it won't work

Comment: @Blue . . . This only uses `to_number()` when the value passes the regular expression check.  There should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

data type mismatch.
short way round it might be to:
"rebuild the target table column to be nvarchar(max)"